# Adding images with no bounding box to tflite model maker object detection dataset

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I want to add images without any bounding boxes to the dataset used to train an object detector using tflite model maker.

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format) I can add

> one row for each image with no bounding box (such as row 4 below).

```
 TRAIN,gs://folder/image1.png,car,0.1,0.1,,,0.3,0.3,,
 TRAIN,gs://folder/image1.png,bike,.7,.6,,,.8,.9,,
 UNASSIGNED,gs://folder/im2.png,car,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3
 TEST,gs://folder/im3.png,,,,,,,,,
```

When doing so I am getting a ValueError "could not convert string to float", which is caused by an attempt to cast the None object to a float in the following [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/c930d0af2983ee438dcc005f9373188734f1624f/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader_util.py#L337-L338):

```
    xmin, ymin = float(line[3]) * width, float(line[4]) * height
```

Does anyone know how to properly add such images without bounding boxes? Are these empty images even helpful towards training the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model Maker doesn't support images without any bounding boxes. Neither will the images used in the training. Thus Please avoid such data.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Should this be classified as a documentation error then? The documentation specified how to use them in the csv file.

Comment: Will throw a warning or error for such data in Model Maker. From Model Maker side, such data are not allowed.